# Application.Exit needs to be called twice

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, pinvoke

I have a Main method that creates a message loop called SysTrayApp:

```
void Main()
{
    Application.Run(new SysTrayApp());
}
```

My SysTrayApp class adds a ContextMenu to the System Tray icon, then starts another message loop called `MouseHook`. MouseHook is a class that pinvokes mouse events. (Modeled after [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589468.aspx) class.)

```
class SysTrayApp : Form
{           
    public SysTrayApp()
    {
        // Does some GUI work    
        // Then starts another message loop
        Application.Run(new MouseHook());
    }
}
```

_

```
class MouseHook : Form
{           
    public MouseHook()
    {
        // Does some hooking stuff      
    }
}
```

In SysTrayApp, `Application.Exit()` is called when the user selects the Exit option from the context menu. The problem is that I have to call Exit twice (or add another `Application.Exit`) for the application to end. This is expected, but 
I feel like I am going about this the wrong way. Calling `Application.Exit()` twice just seems wrong to me, but I'm new to the C# world. Should `SysTrayApp` and `MouseHook` be combined into one big class? `MouseHook` doesn't seem like it should be apart of Windows.Form either. Maybe `MouseHook` needs to be on a new thread? Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** Oops. `MouseHook` did not have a third `Application.Run()`

## Solution

I guess I was over thinking this. Still exploring C#, like I said. But here is what works:

`Application.Run(new SysTrayApp());` in `Main()` is all you need. To start `MouseHook`, just do a `MouseHook hook = new MouseHook();` in `SysTrayApp`.

Thanks @JonSkeet for helping me understand this. You are a machine!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're calling `Application.Run` *in the `MouseHook` constructor* and then when that returns, you're calling `Application.Run` again (in the `SysTrayApp` constructor) - you're then calling it a *third* time when the `SysTrayApp` constructor completes. If you're going to run three different message loops, you should expect to have to exit three times (I'm amazed you're only having to call `Application.Exit` twice).

You shouldn't be calling `Application.Run` in *either* of your constructors - the idea of a constructor blocking until a message pump has finishes is nasty, IMO. If you *really* want multiple message loops, they should be on different threads - but I wouldn't advise you to do that. You should be fine *just* calling `Application.Run` in your `Main` method.

Comment: I realize *why* it happens. And I can workaround it by calling `Application.Exit` twice. But I want to know if this is considered bad practice.

Comment: See it like this. Your calling Application.Run twice. The name suggests that you want to run the application twice. But this is all in the same application. So 1 Appliction.Run and for your mouse hook you could for example use a thread.

Comment: @aus I believe that is answered by the `the idea of a constructor blocking until a message pump has finishes is nasty, IMO`. Why are you making two message loops in the first place that one can not accomplish?

Comment: @aus: Calling `Application.Run` from a constructor? Yes, that's absolutely considered bad practice. Why are you doing it in the first place? The work around isn't to call `Application.Exit` twice - it's to only call `Application.Run` *once*.

Comment: @aus you can simply create a new MouseHook form, you don't need to use Application.Run with it.

Comment: @JonSkeet Right. I agree. So how should I keep `MouseHook` running? Should `MouseHook` be spawned on a new thread?